PCI Express AER driver doesn't insert /dev/aer_inject as device
Currently using the description shown at this site to capture PCI-e AER codes.
All the options related to the custom kernel compilation has been enabled as shown below
cat /boot/config-6.8.0-48-generic | grep -i PCIEAER
CONFIG_ACPI_APEI_PCIEAER=y
CONFIG_PCIEAER=y
CONFIG_PCIEAER_INJECT=y
CONFIG_PCIEPORTBUS=y

When the lspci command is issued the device I'm targeting shows up.
After re-booting my PC (as described in the driver's documentation), the /dev/aer_inject is not listed.
I tried this solution with similar results.
Wondering what another alternative I might try to load the driver. Should the driver be compiled as a kernel module? If that's the case, what's the best way to do so?

The RAS daemon (rasdaemon) provides AER reporting capabilities. Can be found in both Redhat and Ubuntu Linux.
The rasdaemon, however, does not provide /dev/aer_inject. As described earlier, the error message shows up again: Failed to open device /dev/aer_inject, No such file or directory.
The file can be created 'manually' using this description
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/aer_inject c 246 0

However, the same error message would show up

It is not the answer. Rather update your post. Also device file on modern Linux should be created automatically by user space udev or alike.

It should get automatically created as a "misc" device with character special major number 10, and some dynamically allocated minor device number.
